# Screen dimming when user inactive - how to turn off it?

Tags: display

How can I turn off automatic dimming of screen when I am inactive?

I was looking in settings but I coudn't find anythink.

Thank you!

Comment: Dis tou check the "power" menu in settings?

Comment: I set it, but it doesn't work still :/